# Multiple Issues with Google Sheets Scripts (JavaScript)

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

NEEDLES TO SAY, I am very new to this, but trying my hardest to figure all this out.   I have a script right now which actively removes all empty rows from an entire workbook.  But I'm hoping someone can assist is narrowing this down to a single sheet within that workbook.

```
function removeEmptyRows() {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
        .getSheets()
        .forEach(function (s) {
            c = 0;
            s.getRange(1, 1, s.getMaxRows(), s.getMaxColumns())
                .getValues()
                .forEach(function (r, j) {
                    if (r.toString()
                        .replace(/,/g, "")
                        .length == 0) {
                        s.deleteRow((j += 1) - c)
                        c += 1;
                    }
                })
        })
}
```

Ideally I would like for this to remove only blank rows on one sheet within my workbook called 'Racing Results'.  The reason I'm need this, is due to how the spreadsheet is setup and having multiple rows merged together.  So when I copy these results over to a different sheet, there are gaps between them and I'd like them removed.  Here is the script I'm using to copy the data to another sheet.

```
function Copy() {

 var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('18cl69Id4saI455wk__-PhvfxXZa7iWlQpoiRKqBz6bU');
 var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Score Card');
 var range = ss.getRange('A32:E36');
 var data = range.getValues();
 var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('18cl69Id4saI455wk__-PhvfxXZa7iWlQpoiRKqBz6bU');
 var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Race Results');

 ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);

}
```

If not to throw one final monkey wrench into this colossal mess, I have been attempting to copy two different cell ranges within the same script and I feel like this isn't possible because only the latter one gets copied and the initial one is discarded. Here is the other copy script I am using which runs before the one above this.

```
function Copy() {

var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('18cl69Id4saI455wk__-PhvfxXZa7iWlQpoiRKqBz6bU');
 var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Score Card');
 var range = ss.getRange('A1:A1');
 var data = range.getValues();
 var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('18cl69Id4saI455wk__-PhvfxXZa7iWlQpoiRKqBz6bU');
 var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Race Results');

 ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);

}
```

[Score Card Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXDOE.png)

In a perfect world, what I'm trying to get setup is the following. Above is a screenshot of the scorecard we are using.  I am wanting to copy the Current Date (A1) to the 'Racing Results' sheet, then I want to copy the final score with the team names (A32:E36) and move them to the 'Racing Results' sheet right under it.  Once that has been done, I want to remove the empty rows between the results because as of right now this is how it looks when copying over. (see image below)

[Race Results Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FG8Pc.png)

Thanks in advance to anyone who is able to assist with any of this in any way shape or form.

**Edit:
Removing Empty Rows from a spreadsheet is functioning as intended.  Still having issues with Copying multiple times in the same action even when giving them different names.  Here is my updated script.**

```
function CopyDate() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('18cl69Id4saI455wk__-PhvfxXZa7iWlQpoiRKqBz6bU');
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Score Card');
  var range = ss.getRange('A1:A1');//This range is only one cell
  var data = range.getValues();
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('18cl69Id4saI455wk__-PhvfxXZa7iWlQpoiRKqBz6bU');
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Race Results');  
  ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}

function CopyScore() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('18cl69Id4saI455wk__-PhvfxXZa7iWlQpoiRKqBz6bU');
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Score Card');
  var range = ss.getRange('A32:E36');
  var data = range.getValues();
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('18cl69Id4saI455wk__-PhvfxXZa7iWlQpoiRKqBz6bU');
  var ts = tss.getSheetByName('Race Results');  
  ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}

function delBlankRows(shtname){
  var shtname=shtname || 'Race Results';
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName(shtname);
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getMaxRows(),sh.getLastColumn());
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var n=0;
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    if(!vA[i].join("")){
      sh.deleteRow(i-n+1);
      n++;
    }
  }
}

function Sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}

function SaveRaceResults() {
  CopyDate();
  Sleep(5000);
  CopyScore();
  Sleep(5000);
  delBlankRows();
}
```

Comment: Do some refactoring of the first function - create a method that receives a sheet as the input and trims its rows, e.g. `function removeRowsFromSheet(sheet)`. (The code for this is basically written already). Then you use this function in both the code above, and the code you want to use. As for your copy scripts, they have the same name. That means the one written last replaces the previous definition of that name - only one exists to the executing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting All Blank Rows on a Sheet

```
function delBlankRows(shtname){
  var shtname=shtname || 'Sheet1';
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName(shtname);
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getMaxRows(),sh.getLastColumn());
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var n=0;
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    if(!vA[i].join("")){
      sh.deleteRow(i-n+1);
      n++;
    }
  }
}
```

Copy function:

```
function Copy() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ss1 = sss.getSheetByName('Score Card');
  var range1 = ss1.getRange('A1');//This range is only one cell
  var data1 = range1.getValues();
  var ts1 = sss.getSheetByName('Race Results');  
  ts1.getRange(ts1.getLastRow()+1, 1, data1.length, data1[0].length).setValues(data1);
  var ss2 = sss.getSheetByName('Score Card');
  var range2 = ss2.getRange('A32:E36');
  var data2 = range2.getValues();
  var ts2 = sss.getSheetByName('Race Results');  
  ts2.getRange(ts2.getLastRow()+1, 1, data2.length, data2[0].length).setValues(data2);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Cooper! It has helped quite a bit. I am running into an issue with the Copy Script still (it looks basically the same as when I posted it). But I can always get the first copy to work fine, but I can't get the second copy to work right, it always pastes blank cells  Any ideas on how to get multiple cell copies one after the other? If I run one by itself, it is fine, if I run the other by itself, it also works. They are only having issues when I'm trying to run them in succession.

Comment: Are you saying that CopyDate() works and CopyScore() doesn't?

Comment: They both work, when ran separately. If I use the following function edited in above (OP), only the CopyDate seems to actually copy and paste correctly, the CopyScore does not.  However, individually when ran from the script page, they both work fine.  I copied the whole script into the original post for you and I run the 'SaveRaceResults' function at the bottom to trigger everything in order.

Comment: I put them both into the same function and updated my answer and it works fine for me.

Comment: That's great, I didn't think to combine the two together because I figured if they were in the same function they would have overwrote each other.  Thanks again for your help and everything seems to be working perfectly!